# How do you add an administratior in a rails 3 appliction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just built a rails 3 application by using Mike Hartl's "Learn Rails by Example". I am ready to deploy it but I am confused about how to add the administrator  to the application. I will be the only administrator. Will the administrator be added before deployment and if so how do I do this.

Comment: You make it sound like every Rails project by definition has an admin, which is not the case. What do you mean by administrator? Have you written any code that can only be executed by admins? Or is this part of the tutorial you used? In that case at least provide a link to Mike Hartl's "Learn Rails by Example".

Comment: Don't know thistutorial but you could add it to your seeds.

Answer (score 2):

What I believe you need when you talk about an "administrator account" is in fact two different things: authentication (the login) & authorization (what a login can/cannot do).

Under rails, one way to do that is by using two different gems. I suggest you have a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). They have both been developed and are actively maintained by rails superstars: José Valim and Ryan Bates.

Comment: Take a look at one of the "crazy deep" Rails tutorials at http://railsapps.github.com/ to see an example of an app using Devise for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial doesn't actually go through creating an interface where you can create admins. If you want to test the part where you're not allowed to delete other administrator accounts, you can test it with faker by adding 2 admins to the sample_data.rake file:

```
def make_users
  admin = User.create!(:name => "Example User",
                   :email => "example@railstutorial.org",
                   :password => "foobar",
                   :password_confirmation => "foobar")
admin.toggle!(:admin)
admin2 = User.create!(:name => "Example User2",
                   :email => "example2@railstutorial.org",
                   :password => "foobar",
                   :password_confirmation => "foobar")
admin.toggle!(:admin)
99.times do |n|
name  = Faker::Name.name
email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
password  = "password"
User.create!(:name => name,
             :email => email,
             :password => password,
             :password_confirmation => password)
  end
end
```

If you want to add an admin to production, I'm guessing you could create your account and toggle the admin function with a database editor and then push the db to the production server? That's what I would do but I'm by no means an expert.

Answer (score 0):

for admin control panel on my web-apps i'm using typus gem https://github.com/fesplugas/typus/

it will generate an admin page and by the default typus will use your model default_scope to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm busy with the same thing!

I found this on STACK:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0.beta3)
irb(main):001:0> admin = Admin.create! do |u|
irb(main):002:1* u.email = 'sample@sample.com'
irb(main):003:1> u.password = 'password'
irb(main):004:1> u.password_confirmation = 'password'
irb(main):005:1> end
```

I changed the Admin to User, but the problem is it creates a normal user not an admin user. Somewhere we need to put in `- admin.toggle!(:admin)` or make it true. I'll let you know if I find anything else.

Comment: Ok, I got it! ad u.toggle!(:admin)

Comment: just before the <end> part... and remember to put in a u.name as well!